# Overriding method with generics not working (no method found)

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding

I am trying to `@Override` a method in a class that might look like having a complex inheritance structure, but it should actually be quite simple, however I cannot get it to work.

```
public interface Action { }

public interface Result { }

public interface Player<A extends Action, R extends Result> {
    default public <P extends Player<A, R>> void onPostAction(final P target, final A action, final R result) { }
}

abstract public class GesturePlayer<A extends Action, R extends Result> implements Player<A, R> { }

abstract public class RPSPlayer extends GesturePlayer<RPSGesture, RPSResult> { }

public class RPSHumanPlayer extends RPSPlayer {
    @Override
    public void onPostAction(final RPSPlayer target, final RPSGesture gesture, final RPSResult result) { }
}
```

I get the error on the `@Override` of the `onPostAction`, why can it not find the correct method to override?

This is for a Rock-Paper-Scissors implementation for people wondering where the name comes from.

The exact error message:

> method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

My goal is to **still** use the current class, so for `RPSHumanPlayer` I would actually want to have this signature:

```
public void onPostAction(final RPSHumanPlayer target, final RPSGesture gesture, final RPSResult result) { }
```

Comment: And what is the complete and exact error message?

Comment: @JBNizet Added it, but it is not that informative.

Answer (score 3):

The method `onPostAction` in `Player` is itself generic.  You have defined `P` there.  Therefore, any method that overrides it must also be generic.

Try

```
public class RPSHumanPlayer extends RPSPlayer {
    @Override
    public <P extends Player<RPSGesture, RPSResult>> void onPostAction(final P target,
       final RPSGesture gesture, final RPSResult result) { }
}
```

`A` and `R` are already defined by `GesturePlayer` to be `RPSGesture` and `RPSResult`, but `P` still needs to be declared.

**Addition**

If it needs to be that exact signature, then you'll have to define `P` along with `A` and `R` on the `Player` interface:

```
public interface Player<A extends Action, R extends Result, P extends Player<A, R, P>> {
    default public void onPostAction(final P target, final A action, final R result) { }
}
```

Then `GesturePlayer` changes accordingly:

```
abstract public class GesturePlayer<A extends Action, R extends Result,
     P extends Player<A, R, P>> implements Player<A, R, P> { }
```

Then `RPSPlayer` defines itself to be `P`.

```
abstract public class RPSPlayer extends GesturePlayer<RPSGesture, RPSResult, RPSPlayer> { }
```

And `RPSHumanPlayer` can have the method as is:

```
public class RPSHumanPlayer extends RPSPlayer {
    @Override
    public void onPostAction(final RPSPlayer target, final RPSGesture gesture, final RPSResult result) { }
}
```

Comment: Would there be a way to get rid of this in the lower classes (`RPSHumanPlayer`)?

Comment: You could define `P` along with `A` and `R` on the `Player` interface itself instead of on the method.  Then `RPSPlayer` would define itself as `P`.

Comment: I updated the question at the bottom with that I still want to retain the same method signature, sorry for not being clear.

Comment: I've added to my answer.

Comment: It's unfurtunately not of type `RPSHumanPlayer` now, but of `RPSPlayer`, I might see situations where I need that type; could you also explain why it the generics did not work in the first case?