# Why do my generics not take a subclass?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I had a question about similar generics [yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22517047/overriding-method-with-generics-not-working-no-method-found), and as solution I implemented a sort of self-reference in some classes, like this:

```
public interface Action { }

public interface Result { }

public interface Player<A extends Action, R extends Result, P extends Player<A, R, P>> {
    default public void onPostAction(final P target, final A action, final R result) { }
}

abstract public class GesturePlayer<A extends Action, R extends Result, P extends GesturePlayer<A, R, P>> implements Player<A, R, P> { }

abstract public class RPSPlayer extends GesturePlayer<RPSGesture, RPSResult, RPSPlayer> { }

public class RPSHumanPlayer extends RPSPlayer {
    @Override
    public void onPostAction(final RPSHumanPlayer target, final RPSGesture gesture, final RPSResult result) { }
}
```

This code does not compile, hoewver I am unable to figure out why.
It does work if in the `@Override` I use `RPSPlayer`, however `RPSHumanPlayer` is simply a subclass of it, should it not work the same as the following?

```
List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Which also has the type definied as the superclass (`List` resp `RPSPlayer`), and the referenced object's type as the subclass (`ArrayLast` resp `RPSHumanPlayer`).

My aim with this question is to gather insight on how the generics exactly work, and I want to keep the method signature as it is defined in `RPSHumanPlayer`.

What I think I understand about generics:

- `T` is a typed parameter, like `List<String>`, etc. Also able to use it for own classes and methods. This also captures all subclasses of `T`.
- `?` captures all possible `Object`s. Used to ensure that something is generic and not raw.
- `? extends T` capture a specific subclass of `T`.

This code is written on Java 8.

Comment: `class Player<A extends Action, R extends Result, P>` is almost certainly sufficient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to achieve the desired method signature in `RPSHumanPlayer`, you will need to generify `RPSPlayer` like this:

```
abstract public class RPSPlayer<P extends RPSPlayer<P>> extends GesturePlayer<RPSGesture, RPSResult, P> { }
```

Then you can define:

```
public class RPSHumanPlayer extends RPSPlayer<RPSHumanPlayer>
```

In Java, parameter types are part of the method signature, so they can't be changed (not even subclassed). Since Java 5, you can use covariant return types, but that's as far as it goes.

Comment: +1 It works, however I am not too happy with all the generics in the code now. Are there other notable ways to achieve similar behaviour?

Comment: @skiwi If you can't change the signature in `RPSHumanPlayer`, then no, there is no other way.

Comment: @RohitJain Well it is not so much that I *cannot* change it, but I do not want to bloat the method itself with generics and I still want to have methods of `RPSHumanPlayer` accessible, which it would not be in the `RPSPlayer` case.

Comment: @skiwi Well, then this is the way you should do it.

Comment: @RohitJain An extra answer with more explanation behind the generics and the sentence *parameter types are part of the method signature, so they can't be changed* would still be appreciated Though. Aswell as exactly showing what the bounds are of every typed parameter in the inheritance structure. I am still slightly confused.

Comment: @skiwi I'm confused what more to add to the already existing answer. Can you be more explicit about your doubts. The bounds of type parameters are clearly shown in the code. Do you mean erasure?

Comment: @skiwi and Ray: There is no parameter type declared here with method signature. It is just using the one declared with class.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem boils down to this:

```
public interface Player {
    default public void onPostAction(Player target) {}
}

public abstract class HumanPlayer implements Player {
    @Override
    public void onPostAction(HumanPlayer target) {}
}
```

This cannot work, because `onPostAction(HumanPlayer)` cannot override `onPostAction(Player)`, because then what would happen if it was called with a `Player` that was not a `HumanPlayer`?